# Grails 2.3.7 Intellij Scaffold doesn't create list.gsp

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I'm using version 12.1.7 of intellij and I created a controller in grails.

```
class ExampleController {
    static scaffold = true
    ...
}
```

Now when I tell intellij to generate the views, it generates the following

- _form.gsp
- create.gsp
- edit.gsp
- index.gsp
- show.gsp

however it is missing the list.gsp. Is there a specific reason for this? Must I create a list() function first before using scaffolding? You would think list would be a default view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no longer a `list` in grails 2.3.x.  The `index` is considered the list.  If you look at index.gsp, I'm sure you'll see a table.

Comment: Thank you for that. Was driving me nuts.